# android google cardboard getLastHeadView returns NAN matrix when changing activity

Tags: java, android, nan, google-cardboard

I have a cardboard application that only uses the HeadTracker to obtain the orientation of the phone.

It works relatively well until I try to access a different activity (login menu) and then come back to my MainActivity.
The LoginActivity is built using the template provided by AndroidStudio.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mainActivity, LoginActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

When I come back,

```
 mCardboardHeadTracker.getLastHeadView(mHeadViewMatrix, 0);
```

returns an array of NaN. I tried reseting the matrix without success.

Comment: from debugging the decompilation, the NaN matrix comes from:
double[] mat = this.tracker.getPredictedGLMatrix(secondsToPredictForward);

Answer (score 0):

You should call:
                mCardboardHeadTracker.stopTracking();